# Color cell value in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a Table that looks something like this:

[image]

I have an SSRS report that looks something like this:

[image: I am getting the column values of LatencyValue under One Build Number]

I want to color Latency value based on next value.

Based on BuildNumber i will get different LatencyValues in report i grouped BuildNumber and displayed LatencyValues on that build Number. Now the LatencyValues differ for different builds by comparing one latency value to another i want to give color.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try the following: open the Properties pane and use something like the following expression in the Color property:

```
=IIF(Fields!Build1.Value <> Fields!Build2.Value, "Red", "Black")
```

If its only the two builds you are comparing you could modify the underlying sql code so you won't need grouping. If you want to keep the grouping have a look at the following post  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/7af36b3b-080a-4626-abf0-1060fac6f5cb/conditional-formatting-depending-on-previous-cell-in-matrix

Comment: There is only one column not two.